# Pandas: using groupby to calculate a ratio by specific values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, aggregate

[image]

Hi
I have a dataframe that looks like this:

and I want to calculate a ratio in the column 'count_number',
based on the values in the column 'tone' by this formula: ['blue'+'grey']/'red'
per each unite combination of 'participant_id', 'session', 'block' -

here is part of my dataset as text, the left column 'RATIO' is my expected output:

> participant_id    session block   tone    count_number    RATIO
> 10  1   neg blue    0   0
> 10  1   neg grey    0   0
> 10  1   neg red 3   0
> 10  1   neu blue    1   #DIV/0!
> 10  1   neu grey    1   #DIV/0!
> 10  1   neu red 0   #DIV/0!
> 10  2   neg blue    3   2.333333333
> 10  2   neg grey    4   2.333333333
> 10  2   neg red 3   2.333333333
> 10  2   neu blue    4   1.333333333
> 10  2   neu grey    0   1.333333333
> 10  2   neu red 3   1.333333333
> 11  1   neg blue    0   0
> 11  1   neg grey    0   0
> 11  1   neg red 3   0

I tried this (wrong) direction

```
def group(df):
  grouped = df.groupby(["participant_id", "session", "block"])['count_number']
  return grouped

neutral = df.loc[df.tone=='grey']
pleasant = df.loc[df.tone=='blue']
unpleasant = df.loc[df.tone=='red']

df['ratio'] = (group(neutral)+group(pleasant)) / group(unpleasant)
```

Comment: 1) Provide your sample dataframe as text, not picture. 2) What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

We could create separate Series objects for numerator and denominator of the divisions; then `groupby` + transform `sum` + `div` will fetch the desired ratio:

```
num = df['tone'].isin(['blue','grey']) * df['count_number']
denom = df['tone'].eq('red') * df['count_number']
cols = [df[c] for c in ['participant_id', 'session', 'block']]
df['RATIO'] = (num.groupby(cols).transform('sum')
               .div(denom.groupby(cols).transform('sum'))
               .replace(float('inf'), '#DIV/0!'))
```

Another approach could be to use `groupby` + apply a lambda that calculates the required ratio for each group; then map the ratios back to the original DataFrame:

```
cols = ['participant_id', 'session', 'block']
mapping = (df.groupby(cols)
           .apply(lambda x: (x.loc[x['tone'].isin(['blue','grey']), 'count_number'].sum() / 
                             x.loc[x['tone'].eq('red'), 'count_number']))
           .droplevel(-1))

df['RATIO'] = df.set_index(cols).index.map(mapping)
df['RATIO'] = df['RATIO'].replace(float('inf'), '#DIV/0!')
```

Output:

```
    group  participant_id  session block  tone  count_number     RATIO
0       1              10        1   neg  blue             0       0.0
1       1              10        1   neg  grey             0       0.0
2       1              10        1   neg   red             3       0.0
3       1              10        1   neu  blue             1   #DIV/0!
4       1              10        1   neu  grey             1   #DIV/0!
5       1              10        1   neu   red             0   #DIV/0!
6       1              10        2   neg  blue             3  2.333333
7       1              10        2   neg  grey             4  2.333333
8       1              10        2   neg   red             3  2.333333
9       1              10        2   neu  blue             4  1.333333
10      1              10        2   neu  grey             0  1.333333
11      1              10        2   neu   red             3  1.333333
12      1              11        1   neg  blue             0       0.0
13      1              11        1   neg  grey             0       0.0
14      1              11        1   neg   red             3       0.0
```